Startup Applications program freezes after selecting add
I run the Startup Applications program and select the "Add" option. Then I select the "Browse..." option and the application freezes with the grayed out coloring.
The machine and operating system are still working fine, there is no apparent crash, just the grayed out frozen Startup Applications window
Edit: after several minutes the popup appeared and the application became active again
Any idea why this is happening and how to remedy the situation?
New installation 24.04.1 LTS
